# Trying to publish the report in Jenkins with HTML Publisher plugin - jmeter maven plugin

Tags: performance, maven, jenkins, jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

Java: 8
Maven: 3.2.5``
JMeter-Maven-Plugin: 2.7.0

I also have this same use case, trying to publish the report in Jenkins with HTML Publisher plugin.

> tarting process with:[java, -Xms512M, -Xmx512M, -jar,
>   ApacheJMeter-4.0.jar, -d,
>   /home/jenkins/workspace/QA_automation/Performance_Job_ISL/target/jmeter,
>   -e, -j, /home/jenkins/workspace/QA_automation/Performance_Job_ISL/target/jmeter/logs/Jmeter.jmx.log,
>   -l, /home/jenkins/workspace/QA_automation/Performance_Job_ISL/target/jmeter/results/Jmeter.csv,
>   -n, -o, /home/jenkins/workspace/QA_automation/Performance_Job_ISL/target/jmeter/reports/Jmeter_20190130_051346,
>   -t, /home/jenkins/workspace/QA_automation/Performance_Job_ISL/target/jmeter/testFiles/Jmeter.jmx]

What to use to get html report in HTML Publisher plugin... Please suggest
HTML directory to archive & Index page[s]

Comment: Any feedback on answer ? If ok it should be accepted and upvoted  so that others can use it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In order to do that , you need to:

- Use [jmeter-maven-plugin](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) version >= 2.8.2 since this issue was fixed as bug [295](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/issues/295)
- Then if your plan is named [jenkins-demo.jmx](https://github.com/ubikloadpack/demo-jenkins/tree/master/src/test/jmeter) , the path to configure will be

> ${WORKSPACE}/target/jmeter/reports/jenkins-demo/

To end up with:

[image: Post build action configuration]